# Where to find the best user story template?

Tags: templates, agile, methodology, extreme-programming

I want to implement user stories in a new project where can i find a good template or other ones used in agile development?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See the Nine boxes technique to elaborate your user stories. 
It's not really a template per se, but it leads to filling the "**as a user, I want ... so that ...**" template, which is very efficient. [Mike Cohn is explaining this better than I would](http://blog.mountaingoatsoftware.com/?p=24).

It also allows to discover non-functional requirements (the *[**ilities**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_system_quality_attributes)*).

EDIT: the original link to the nine-boxes page is now cybersquatted but the page is available on the [internet archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20071217082912/http://dnicolet1.tripod.com/agile/index.blog/1765142/nine-boxes/).

Comment: The supplied Nine boxes link is broken.  Here's one that I found that seems to be good: http://www.agilecoach.net/coach-tools/the-nine-boxes/

Answer (score 23):

The best template I have found is:

```
As a <user> I want to <do something> so that <I can accomplish goal>.
```

Comment: I read a paper which also noted this template. The "goal" can also be seen as "business value"

Answer (score 15):

Alistair Cockburn has a [use-case template](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Basic+use+case+template). Dan North adopts it to [user stories](http://dannorth.net/whats-in-a-story).

Answer (score 9):

a better one that focuses user's goal more is:

```
In order to <accomplish a goal>, as a <user> I want to <do something>
```

this format encourages everyone to think about what the user is trying to achieve and can hint your team to change user's role or rethink the whole US.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the meat of a User Story is in the *conversation* with the Customer, and in the automated acceptance test: http://www.xprogramming.com/xpmag/expCardConversationConfirmation.htm

Comment: seems like the link is broken